Proving recurrence relation by mathematical induction(related to merge sort)
I have the following recurrence relation:
$T(1) = 1$
$T(n) =  T(\lfloor n/2\rfloor) +  T(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + n$
When proving by induction,by assuming that $n=2^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$
I get that $T(n) = n\log(n) + n$
But I'm not certain how does it show that $T(n) \in θ(nlog(n))$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
Since it was proven for 2' powers, how can i show that non 2's powers T(n) is also bounded within $θ(nlogn)$
Edit: I still don't understand how solving this for 2's powers bounds the function to $Θ(n\log n)$

I have a question. How would you find the value of $T(3)$?

@Gwen T(3) = T(1) + T(2) + 3
T(2) = T(1) + T(1) + 2 right?
so T(2) = 4 and T(3) = 8

I think you probably meant to write $T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + T(\lceil n/2 \rceil) + n$, otherwise this doesn't make sense as a definition of a function with domain $\Bbb N$, which is what I believe Gwen is getting at. For your question: can you show that $T$ is an increasing function?

@IzaakvanDongen yes, i edited it, i made a mistake, please refer to the edited T function

Does this answer your question? Solving recurrence relation - found using an Approach0 search. Note I assume your $θ$ represents $\Theta$, i.e., Knuth's Big Theta notation, as explained in Family of Bachmann–Landau notations. ...

Yes @IzaakvanDongen . How could I have found $T(1.5)$. Anyways it's alright typos can happen of course

(cont.) Another basic duplicate, where the actual $T(n)$ function is determined, is in $t(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor)+t(\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil)+n=n(\lfloor\log n\rfloor+3)-2^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor +1}$. Also, FYI, note that the search also has other somewhat related questions where the final $n$ term in the recurrence relation is replaced with $0$, $1$ and $2$.

@JohnOmielan I'm not certain how the LHS equals to RHS
